# How can I use a jQuery event to detect changes in an input box?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

If I use use `$('element').change(...`, it'll only detect when the element loses focus. I need to detect it constantly (keypress, copy/paste, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should handle the `input` (browsers) and `propertychange` (IE) events.
This will catch drag&drop and paste events too.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/nt4SD/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to detect constantly, use .keyup() instead of .change()